# Docker daemon fails to process logs

Tags: json, docker, logging, debian, daemon

Docker daemon is unable to parse the json log and throws an `unexpected EOF` error. We are investigating the root cause of the issue.

**Environment:**

- Debian 4.9.189-3+deb9u2
- Docker engine 19.03.5

**Docker daemon log:**

```
Apr 29 14:31:05 Prod-IS dockerd[30810]: time="2020-04-29T14:31:05.070677515+02:00" level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=345
Apr 29 14:31:05 Prod-IS dockerd[30810]: time="2020-04-29T14:31:05.070695689+02:00" level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=346
Apr 29 14:31:05 Prod-IS dockerd[30810]: time="2020-04-29T14:31:05.070712630+02:00" level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=347
Apr 29 14:31:05 Prod-IS dockerd[30810]: time="2020-04-29T14:31:05.070732299+02:00" level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=348
Apr 29 14:31:05 Prod-IS dockerd[30810]: time="2020-04-29T14:31:05.070755016+02:00" level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=349
Apr 29 14:31:05 Prod-IS dockerd[30810]: time="2020-04-29T14:31:05.070773699+02:00" level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=350
```

**Docker daemon configuration**

```
"log-driver": "json-file",
"log-opts": {
  "mode": "non-blocking",
  "max-size": "500m",
  "max-file": "3"
}
```

Storage space is available on partition where docker writes its logs.

Your insight in the matter is most welcome.

Comment: We ended up disabling docker logs meanwhile and the cpu usage on `containerd` process returned back to normal.

Comment: You weren't able to figure out a root cause @Mysteryos?

Comment: @PaulRichter We have not. Logs are still disabled. It was on debian OS. We are thinking of moving to Ubuntu.

Comment: An update on this situation: We found out that a deployed application container was outputting erroneous JSON logs and had to correct the latter. The best way to mitigate this error is to keep tiny docker log files such as `max-size` = `10m` until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The aforementioned issue will cause an abnormal spike in CPU usage of the docker (version <= 19) process and constantly stay at that level until you fix the logs.

To fix the logs & cpu usage, you've to truncate all the container logs (since we are unable to determine which container has faulty logs). It works only if your logs are in json format:

```
truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log
```

Please see Andre's answer for a permanent fix.

Comment: On mac desktop I had to first log into the vm with

`docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid=host justincormack/nsenter1`

Then run 

`truncate -s 0 /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*-json.log`

Answer (score 5):

Issue=Docker Engine Error json-file: fix sporadic unexpected EOF errors

I had spent some time researching and trying to find errors in the docker
logs.

There is a bug in docker engine 20.10.5 which is the version running in docker. A Github PR fixes this. https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/42104

I found the error while running

```sh
$ journalctl -u docker.service
level=warning msg="got error while decoding json" error="unexpected EOF" retries=19999
```

Docker driver for logs has a bug and it wont handle some log formatting. The bug then floods the system's log with retries messages. This situation generates a very annoying CPU load.

Docker engine latest is 20.10.7. The issue has been fixed in release Docker engine 20.10.6 https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#20106